# How to pass object as a reactive object via provide/inject

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Vue 3 with options API.

I would like to pass map object from one component to another on via provide/inject. I referred to the [official website](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#working-with-reactivity).

As mentioned in the aforementioned link, it uses the following style:

```
provide() {
  return {
    // explicitly provide a computed property
    message: computed(() => this.message)
  }
}
```

I am following the same style but VS Code underlines the `computed(()=>` with red and the error message is never indicative on the real error.
How should `provide` object and `inject` object look?

I want the map object to be reactive

**first attempts to solve it**:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map,
        };
    },
    provide: {
        [SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description]: this.compPropsMap,
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsMap() {
            return this.map;
        },
    },
}
```

**second attempt**:

```
in this attempt, in the `injector` component, the value of 
`mapInstance` is `undefined`
i do provide in `onMount` and inside `nextTick`
//provider component

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map,
        };
    },
    methods: {
        async renderMap() {
            map = mapViewModel.getMap();
            provide(SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description, computed(()=> map));
        }
    }
}   

//injector component
const mapInstance = inject(SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description);

export default {
    methods: {
        onDigitizePolygon() {
            console.info(debugTag, 'mapInstance:', mapInstance);
        },
    },
}
```

Vue component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            map,
        };
    },
    provide: {
        [SysConstants.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description]: computed(() => this.map)
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. the provided component should contain the following:

```
provide() {
    return {
        [InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description]: computed(() => map),
    };
```

},

while the injector component should be like:

```
export default {
    inject: {
        injected: { from: InjectionKeys.PROVIDE_KEY_MAP_INSTANCE.description },
    },
    data() {
        return {
        ....
        ....
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        console.log('injected:', this.injected);
    },
```